# How to pass multiple props from parent to child component in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to pass two properties from parent to child, but for some reason this isn't working and all the examples I've found refer to passing a single property. What I've tried to do is:

Parent vue component:

```
<template>
  <div class="statistics_display">
    <multiLineChart :rowsA="reading['A'].price_stats" :rowsB="reading['B'].price_stats"></multiLineChart>
  </div>
</template>
```

multiLineChart vue component:

```
export default {
  name: 'MultiLineChart',
  props: ['rowsA', 'rowsB'],
  mounted: function() {
      console.log(this.rowsA);
  }
```

the console log is returning undefined. If I executethe exact same code and pass a single prop, it returns the expected prop contents. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you get undefined because `reading['A'].price_stats` is undefined?

Comment: `['rowsA, rowsB']` - this means an array with one string value `'rowsA, rowsB'`. Just remove quotation marks.

Comment: yeah, ^ this one

Comment: @oniondomes that was actually a typo from simplifying the code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Then you have a valid code. @samayo could be right and you might have no value for `reading['A'].price_stats`. Make some tests or try to reproduce the error in another environment.

Comment: @samayo It's defined in the parent as an array of integers. If I pass it as a single prop, it is also defined in the child as the exact same thing. Only when I pass it along with another prop it turns undefined.

Comment: I think I got it. Try not to use camel case for prop names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML attributes are case-insensitive, so

```
<multiLineChart :rowsA="reading['A'].price_stats" :rowsB="reading['B'].price_stats"></multiLineChart>
```

Are actually bound to `props: ['rowsa', 'rowsb']`.

If you want `props: ['rowsA', 'rowsB']`to work, use, in the template: `:rows-a="..."` and `:rows-b="..."`.

See it working below.

```js
Vue.component('multilinechart', {
  template: "#mtemplate",
  props: ['rowsA', 'rowsB'],
  mounted: function() {
      console.log(this.rowsA, this.rowsB);
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    reading: {A: {price_stats: 11}, B: {price_stats: 22}}
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="statistics_display">
    <multiLineChart :rows-a="reading['A'].price_stats" :rows-b="reading['B'].price_stats"></multiLineChart>
  </div>
</div>

<template id="mtemplate">
  <div>I'm multilinechart</div>
</template>
```