# How to pass a prop from parent to child in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a parent component called **Stepper** which contains this child component called **ShortSummary**. I am trying to pass a prop from **Stepper** to **ShortSummary** by clicking on a radiobutton. but it doesn't work! Here's what I have done. This is **Stepper**:

```
<v-radio-group row v-model="voltage" >
    <v-radio
    v-for="n in radioNames"
    :key="n"
    :label="n"
    :value="n"></v-radio>
</v-radio-group>

<app-short-summary :voltage="voltage" ></app-short-summary>

<script>
import ShortSummary from "./ShortSummary";
    data() {
      return {
        voltage:'',
        radioNames:
        ['24V to 36V',
          '48V to 72V',
          '96V to 110V']
    },
    components:{
      appShortSummary: ShortSummry
    }
}
</script>
```

and this is **ShortSummary**:

```
<v-list-tile
    :key="item.title"
    avatar
    ripple
    @click="toggle(index)">
    <v-list-tile-content>
         {{item.action}}
    </v-list-tile-content>
</v-list-tile>

<script>
export default {
  props:['voltage']
  data () {
    return {
      selected: [2],
      items: [
        {
          action: `Voltage: ${this.voltage}`
        },
        {
          action: 'Weight: POOF'
        },
        {
          action: 'Size: BOOM'
        },
        {
          action: '2oo2? Need the logic document'
        },
        {
          action: 'Price: Very very expensive'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

currently it shows *voltage* as blank. I want *`Voltage: ${this.voltage}`* to show the value of voltage selected from the radiobutton on **Stepper**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass multiple props from parent to child component in Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49079455/how-to-pass-multiple-props-from-parent-to-child-component-in-vue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Component's `data` object is initialized before `this` is available, hence `this.voltage` is undefined.

Instead make your `items` as computed prop.

```
<script>
export default {
  props:['voltage']
  data () {
    return {
      selected: [2],
    }
  },
  computed: {
   items() {
     return [
        {
          action: `Voltage: ${this.voltage}`
        },
        {
          action: 'Weight: POOF'
        },
        {
          action: 'Size: BOOM'
        },
        {
          action: '2oo2? Need the logic document'
        },
        {
          action: 'Price: Very very expensive'
        }
      ]
   }
}
</script>
```